# How to publish a Flutter desktop application to Windows Store

Tags: flutter, dart, windows-store-apps, desktop-application

How can I upload a Flutter desktop application in [Windows Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Store) with the beta version of Flutter 2.02? My desktop application is working fine with version 2.02.

I created a windows build with:

```
flutter build windows
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At first, you need [a paid developer account](https://developer.microsoft.com/microsoft-store/register/). You get a developer account under US$20 (one-time purchases).

Then you build your app with Flutter for Windows. And after this step, you can use the **xsix** package to build a *.xsix* file for the Windows Store. Refer to [the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/msix/latest/) for the package.

Add this package to the *dev_dependencies* part:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  msix: ^2.1.1
```

If you publish your *.msix* file to Windows Store, you don’t need to sign it; Windows Store does it for you. To generate a *.msix* file for Windows Store, use the `--store` flag or add `store: true` in the msix configuration section in your *pubspec.yaml* file.

Note:

the configuration values *publisher_display_name*, *identity_name*, *msix_version*, and *publisher* must be valid. You can find those values in your Windows Store Dashboard → *Product* → *Product identity*.

For more information, please see this tutorial: *[How to publish your MSIX package to the Microsoft Store](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-publish-microsoft-store.html)*

And then use these comments:

```
flutter clean
flutter build windows
flutter pub run msix:create --store
```

After these steps, you get the *.msix* file for uploading to the Windows Store.

Comment: it will give debug msix  but we need to sign that msix and then to publish.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a Microsoft Partner Center account.

You can use the Flutter `msix` package to build the .msix file.

The whole process from building to publishing is [described here](https://blog.codemagic.io/publishing-flutter-windows-apps/).

Comment: May you please describe how your answer differs from the one by @FantaMagier?

Comment: I gave the link to the tutorial that I know to be working @Ruli. It covers all the steps in one place.

Comment: the link content should be described throughout the answer, so it is still valid even if the linked content gets changed or is removed. Please edit the answer and add all the necessary information. The link should be only to support the answer.